# Error on Declaring variable in for statement

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, variables, for-loop

Is declaring a variable within **for** not allowed in C?
Here is the code,

```
for(int i = 1; i<max; i++)
```

And I get error messages as,
**error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'**
**error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier**

It works if I declare the variable **i** jut before the for loop,

```
int i;
for(i = 1; i<max; i++)
```

I was never expecting an error message on such a simple line of code. Can you please help me explain the reason behind this?

**Edit:**
I've Visual C++ 2010 Express. I'm using the command line compiler **cl**.

**Update:**
Based on replies, I've found Visual C++ 2010 doesn't support C98.

I've finally installed Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop which supports C98 and is working as expected. 
Thanks to all of you for the valuable information.

Comment: In C you have to declare all your variables at the start of a {...} block, in c++ you can declare them anywhere - and inside for()

Comment: Try `gcc -std=c99 yourFile.c` to compile your code using the C99 standard, which allows this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older MSVC versions support only c89 standard.

pre-C99 standards, like c89 do not allow declaring variable in for-loop-params.

Maybe use `/TP` option, which causes files to be compiled in C++ mode.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using pre-C99 standard compiler. In C89/ANSI C you have to declare variables in the beginning of the scope block. Pay attention to that because you will most likely get similar errors from declaring variables after you have made some function calls etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's only allowed in C99. Not sure what compiler you're using, clang and gcc have std=c99.

Comment: I'm using the Microsoft's command line compiler which comes with Visual C++ 2010 (Express edition).

Comment: @gstackoverflow I don't see how your question relates to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's C99, and your compiler is probably too old or not set correctly to use this "new" standard.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is very poor when it comes to C and only supports a 24 years old, obsolete version of C called C90. And it supports that version poorly. Microsoft has no strictly conforming C compiler.

If you use a real C compiler instead, the code will compile just fine.